# Negative Turns Ratio on Transformer

Tags: transformer

What does negative turns ratio in the transformer mean?
Some simulation software offers negative turns ratio, but in reality it does not exist.
So what does it mean?

Comment: The negative probably means that the dot notation becomes reversed i.e. still the same ratio of primary and secondary RMS voltages but the phase of the secondary goes through an inversion when negative.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that before, but if I had to guess I would agree with @Andyaka.

Comment: @Andyaka That makes sense but there is also a section related to the polarity.

Comment: You have to think in terms of variables and, if the turns ratio can be voltage controlled, it becomes useful. Having a section that is unalterable in some dynamic modes (transient analysis for instance) is restrictive.